# What is considered a statement in C++?

Tags: c++

My professor commonly asks my class how many statements there are in a given program, but I can't determine what he defines as a statement.  It seems as though an if/else is one statement, and a for loop is one statement regardless of if there are other supposed statements within it.  Are there any governing rules for this matter or is his definition of his own invention?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen anyone worry about the number of statements in a given program.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I suppose he isn't evil enough to just remove points from my average without a motive.

Comment: I guess that he wants to know that the students have grasped where a statement begins and ends. His method of counting would seem to be valid (but not the only valid method of counting).

Comment: He's probably thinking of statements as LOC which is more relevant to count with trying to relate LOC counts to developer workload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a precise [definition](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/statementdefn.htm) of a statement:

Definition: A statement is a block of code that does something. An assignment statement assigns a value to a variable. A for statement performs a loop. 
In C, C++ and C# Statements can be grouped together as one statement using curly brackets

{ 
 statement1;
 statement2;
 }

As far as counting statements, I agree with the others, there's not much point. Counting Lines of Code (LOC) though, actually has some value and there's a lot of research that tries to relate the number of LOC to the workload of developers. It's possible that your instructor is having you count statements and thinking of statements as nothing more than a single LOC, which isn't quite the case.

Answer (score 1):

Statements nest, i.e. smaller statements can be joined into larger statements, like compound statements. For this reason, the question about "how many statements are there in this program" are ambiguous. One has to define the counting method first. Without it the question of "how many" makes little sense.

Comment: Yes, that is why I get confused, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that handles statements parsing in JS alike language:

```
static void do_statement(CsCompiler *c )
{
    int tkn;
    switch (tkn = CsToken(c)) {

    case T_IF:          do_if(c);       break;
    case T_WHILE:       do_while(c);    break;
    case T_WITH:        do_with(c);     break;
    case T_DO:          do_dowhile(c);  break;
    case T_FOR:         do_for(c);      break;
    case T_BREAK:       do_break(c);    CsSaveToken(c,CsToken(c)); break;
    case T_CONTINUE:    do_continue(c); CsSaveToken(c,CsToken(c)); break;
    case T_SWITCH:      do_switch(c);   break;
    case T_CASE:        /*do_case(c);*/    CsParseError(c,"'case' outside of switch");  break;
    case T_DEFAULT:     /*do_default(c);*/ CsParseError(c,"'default' outside of switch");  break;
    case T_RETURN:      do_return(c);   break;
    case T_DELETE:      do_delete(c);   break;
    case T_TRY:         do_try(c);      break;
    case T_THROW:       do_throw(c);    break;
    case '{':           do_block(c, 0); break;
    case ';':           ;               break;
    default:  
      {
        CsSaveToken(c,tkn);
        do_expr(c);
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

As you see it includes things like `for`, `while` and also expressions (separated by `;`)

Answer (score -1):

> In computer programming a statement
>   can be thought of as the smallest
>   standalone element of an imperative
>   programming language. A program is
>   formed by a sequence of one or more
>   statements. A statement will have
>   internal components (e.g.,
>   expressions).

[More at Statement (Computer Science) at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: That's not quite correct since you can have block or compound statements, which are not the smallest, standalone element.

Comment: @Zach: A compound or block statement is still a statement.

Comment: Yes, which is the point I was trying to make. A compound or a block statement is not necessarily the smallest, standalone element of an imperative programming language as you've described. To quickly contrive an example, arbitrarily take a set of statements, put some curly braces around them, and now you have a block statement, which is not the smallest, standalone element but can actually be a large, complex element.