# Populate vector with integer sequence, on construction

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to populate a `vector` (or other container) with a sequence of integers *on construction* of the vector (contrasting to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694579/use-stdfill-to-populate-vector-with-increasing-numbers)).  The following code does what I intend, using the [range constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) for a `vector`, and Boost's [counting_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/counting_range.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<int> test_vector(boost::counting_range(2,10).begin(),boost::counting_range(2,10).end());
    for (auto i : test_vector)  cout << i << endl;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I eliminate the duplication in `counting_range(2,10).begin()` and `counting_range(2,10).end()`?  Currently I'm specifying the range of (2,10) twice.

   Can this be done without Boost, using just vanilla C++11 or C++0x? *Edit:* or C++14?

**Edit:**

- I'd like to instantiate the vector and specify the range all in a single [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891901/what-is-considered-a-statement-in-c).  For example in Python I could write `test_vector=range(2,9)`.  In R/Octave/Matlab one can write `test_vector=2:9` or `test_vector=seq(2,9,1)`.  In this regard I'm satisfied with what I have above.

  I used "2" and "10" above, but boundary of the range could be dynamic, any integers *a*,*b* in scope with *a≤b*.  So an initialization list like {2,3,...,9} isn't desirable since it must be specified at compile-time.

  The method I've used above can also be used to initialize other containers in a single statement; the following also works:

  `unordered_set test_set(boost::counting_range(2,10).begin(),boost::counting_range(2,10).end());`

  It would be nice if any solution was also as 'container independent'.

  I agree with @david-rodriguez-dribeas that we can adhere to Meyer's Item by initializing the vector in the constructor's body; it isn't necessary for it to be done in the constructor's initialization list.  So I have struck-out this portion below.

**Motivation**:

I want to do this is because I want to obey Meyer's Item 4 ("Make sure objects are initialized before they are used.") in Effective C++ elsewhere in my code.  For example:

```
class my_class {
public:
    my_class()
    :vec(boost::counting_range(2,10).begin(),boost::counting_range(2,10).end()) {}
    vector<int> vec;
};
```

Comment: With your example, you may use the initializer list constructor : `vec {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't over do it. The simple thing to do is to default initialize the vector, reserve and initialize from the range.

> *Make sure objects are initialized before they are used.*

That does not mean that the member must be fully initialized in the initialization list, rather than the `my_class` object must be fully initialized when the constructor completes.

Other than that, just for the sake of it, there are different things you can do in vanilla C++ to handle this, like creating a helper function and returning the vector by value:

```
std::vector<int> create_vector() {
   std::vector<int> v;
   // ...
   return v;
}
```

But I would not use this (or any other alternative) to initialize a member, only if *needed* (the vector is `const` might be sufficient excuse :))

Comment: This looks like the best answer, at least for the current state of C++.  It's come a long way, but I don't think there is any good way to make a sequence in a single line.

Comment: @user39275 to the contrary - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can constructor `std::vector<T>` with a sequence delimited by ranges. You just need a suitable input iterator to initialize the sequence and you can define your iterator such that you can use a default constructed iterator for the `end`, e.g.:

```
class counter: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int> {
    int current;
    int end;
public:
    counter(): current(), end() {}
    counter(int c, int e): current(c), end(e) {}
    int const& operator*() const { return this->current; }
    counter& operator++() { ++current; return *this; }
    counter  operator++(int) { counter rc(*this); ++current; return rc; }
    bool operator== (counter const& other) const {
        return (end - current) == (other.end - other.current);
    }
    bool operator!= (counter const& other) const { return !(*this == other); }
};

std::vector<int> v(counter(2, 10), counter());
```

Comment: That is a weird looking iterator... `counter(2,10) == counter(3,11)`, although the values generated by both iterators are different...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez: The iterator has just the required members of InputIterators (well, it should have; if something isn't quite right that's an oversight). The requirements don't make any statements about comparing two iterators from two different sequences! Yes, the two iterator objects you quoted compare equal but that doesn't matter because they win't show up in the same sequence.

Comment: I feel like this is too much code for something that I did above (albeit in an admittedly flawed manner) in a line.

Comment: @user39275: The iterator above is a general tool and should probably go into a header. the actual initialization is just one line, too, and a short one than yours! ... and it doesn't depend on Boost.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, it's definitely something I can learn from, e.g. deriving std::iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost way to do this is to use [`boost::copy_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html):

```
auto vec = boost::copy_range<std::vector<int>>(boost::irange(0, 10));
```

`boost::copy_range` is a function template that returns an object of its first template parameter type:

```
template< typename SeqT, typename Range >
inline SeqT copy_range( const Range& r )
{
    return SeqT( boost::begin( r ), boost::end( r ) );
}
```

You do have to specify the return type as a template parameter, which can violate DRY but can be avoided using [AAA](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) style, as in my example above, or using decltype in a class initializer:

```
class S {
public:
    S() : vec(boost::copy_range<decltype(vec)>(boost::irange(0, 10)) {}
private:
    const std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has *never* failed anyone, and it's completely vanilla, even works with C++03 (provided you backport `begin`, `end`, like I did; if not, just use compile-time array size):

```
int inits[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
vector<int> test_vector ( begin(inits), end(inits) );
```

If the sequence is another kind of sequence, you only need to adapt your initialization array for it, or use a generator object, and bam! It's done.

As for avoid the duplication in (1), what's wrong if anything with the following?

```
const boost::counting_range init_range(2,10);
vector<int> test_vector( begin(init_range), end(init_range) );
```

Comment: he wants to use it in a constructor, so can't do temporary variable.

Comment: Ah, missed that part, though to be fair it is not obvious in the question - it is merely an addendum at the bottom. Still, then the generator helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating boost::counting_range, you can use directly boost::counting_iterator to initialize your sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

int main () 
{
    std::vector<int> aVec(boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(10));
    for (int i : aVec)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```